# Can not get param from json request when using spring aop

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-aop

I am using spring AOP to check permission

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class PermissionManager {
   @Around(value = "@annotation(requiredPermission) && args(id,..)", argNames = "id,requiredPermission")

public Object checkCanViewFile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String id, RequiredPermission permission) throws Throwable {
  ...
}
}
```

Controller

```
@RequiredPermission(RequiredPermission.OperationType.editProject)
@RequestMapping("/searchFile")
public @ResponseBody
WebFile search(String id, String word) throws TokenExpiredException, FetchException    {

...
}
```

It works on spring mvc test but can not working on real environment.   the value of 'id' is null,  I doubt spring AOP get this method before jackson objectmapper,  is it right? How can fix it?